# Why does commented out php code still run on Wordpress themes?

Tags: wordpress-theming

In the `home.html` file of the [twentytwentythree theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentythree/blob/trunk/templates/home.html), the php code still seems to have an effect on the output:

```
<!-- wp:template-part {"slug":"header","tagName":"header"} /-->

    <!-- wp:group {"tagName":"main","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"top":"var:preset|spacing|50","bottom":"var:preset|spacing|70"}}},"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
    
<main class="wp-block-group" style="margin-top:var(--wp--preset--spacing--50);margin-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--70)">
        <!-- wp:heading {"level":1,"align":"wide","style":{"spacing":{"margin":{"bottom":"var:preset|spacing|60"}}}} -->

        <h1 class="alignwide" style="margin-bottom:var(--wp--preset--spacing--60)">Mindblown: a blog about philosophy.</h1>
        <!-- /wp:heading -->
```

Is this standard practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not PHP, this is the markup used for Blocks by Wordpress starting from 5.9

As explained here : https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/key-concepts/

> Blocks are an abstract unit for structuring and interacting with content. When composed together they create the content for a webpage. Everything from a paragraph, to a video, to the site title is represented as a block.

This is the new way of building WP themes to allow full site editing for users.